# How do I create a Slider in FLTK with multiple handles?

Tags: c++, fltk

I want to achieve this
[image]

But as far as I'm aware, [FL_Slider](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Slider.html) does not have built-in support for this. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Are you using the handles or just using it as a display.  If you are just using it as a display, you could override slider_size and set the v parameter greater than 1.  You may also need to override scrollvalue

Comment: I wanted to use the handles, to define a range

Comment: Is there a min and max value for each handle?  If say the bottom cannot go over 50 and the top cannot go under 50, then you could put 2 together and reverse the direction of the 50-100 slider.

Comment: My use case is to manipulate the RGB channels of an image, so both handles need to span the range from 0 - 255. Additionally, min should always be less than max.

Comment: Could you use a scrollbar.  The problem is overriding the handle.  Fl_Widget's handle is virtual but none of the child widgets have virtual handles.  You will have to work out whose handle will be called when you click on the arrows.  It doesn't always follow the C++ rules because the handles are sometimes lost in casting from void*.

Comment: Have you had a look at color_chooser in the example programs?  Click on the fl_choose_color button.  It has a colour selector there.